# TSFをUILessで使うとき、予測変換リストにフォーカスが移った契機を知りたい

Tags: c++, windows

文字を入力すると、予測変換リストが得られますがMS-IMEの場合先頭の項目が選択済みになっており、Tab、下矢印を押下すると2つ目が選択されてしまいます。
予測変換リストウィンドウを表示していると、リストは未選択になっており、Tab、下矢印を押下すると1つ目が選択されるという普通の動きにしたいです。
（Google日本語入力では、非表示の場合予測変換リストは得られず、Tab、下矢印押下後に得られるようになるので、上記の問題は発生しませんが、できればMS-IMEのように文字列入力タイミングで得られる方法があれば知りたいです）

文字を入力しているだけの状態は予測変換リストは非アクティブ状態で、Tab、下矢印を押下したタイミングで予測変換ウィンドウにフォーカスが移るので、このタイミングをUILess状態でも把握できれば、項目の１番目を強制的に選択させるようにすれば解決すると思いました。

非表示の場合フォーカスの概念がなさそうな気もしますが、上記方法以外でも直接的に解決するための方法を知っている方がいたらご教授お願いします。

背景
フルスクリーンのゲームを作る際、ＩＭＥの制御を行って漢字変換をさせる仕組みを用意する際この問題にぶつかりました。
Mincraftで確認したら予測変換リストは自前表示せず、そのまま表示されていました。
他のゲームをあまり知らないんですが、変換リストはそのまま別Window表示が主流なんでしょうか？